# Promise returns null value although it exist in DB

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await, sequelize.js

I am trying to create a DB for school. In this DB I want to store Class name with properties with `sessionId` is `foreign key` which is referencing to `session` table.

Similarly, I am storing `students` with foreign key `classId`

`students` array at the first line is coming from other function which perfectly working.

Problem is here when I create new session then get stored in DB and `newSession` variable also gets value but it not comes in class creation. It comes as null. Here `sessionId: newSession.id` it comes as null.

Similar class get stored in db with nulled `sessionId` and while creating `Student` the `newClass.id` comes null. Although class is perfectly get stored in DB.

What's the problem in code? Why `newClass.id` and `newSession.id` comes as null while creating `Student` and `Class`

```
students.forEach(async function(student) {
  //Create Session 
  let newSession = await Session.findOrCreate({
      where: {
        name: student.session,
        startDate: student.sStartDate,
        endDate: sEndDate
      }
    })
    .then(newSession => {
      return newSession;
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
  //Create Class
  let newClass = await Class.findOrCreate({
      where: {
        name: student.class
      },
      defaults: {
        name: student.class,
        sessionId: newSession.id
      }
    })
    .then(newClass => {
      return newClass;
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));

  //Create a student.
  Student.findOrCreate({
      where: {
        id: student.id
      },
      defaults: {
        id: student.id,
        name: student.name,
        fphone: student.fphone,
        fname: student.fname,
        classId: newClass.id
      }
    })
    .then(newStudent => {
      // console.log(JSON.stringify(newStudent, null, 4)); 
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
});

res.send(students);
}
```

Comment: What ORM are you using?

Comment: it is sequelize.js

Comment: At the very least: ff you're using `await`, don't use `.then()`. The point of `await` is to not have to use then/catch syntax but instead write your code as if it's "normal" code, with function returns, and optional try/catch wrapping. `let newSession = await Session.findOrCreate({...})` and done: `newSession` will be whatever the promise resolution of `Session.findOrCreate` yields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the manual, `findOrCreate returns an array containing the object that was found or created and a boolean that will be true`, so you're using the result incorrectly.

https://sequelize.org/master/manual/models-usage.html

Try something like this:

```
let newSession = null;
try {
  const sessionResult = await Session.findOrCreate({
    where: {
      name: student.session,
      startDate: student.sStartDate,
      endDate: sEndDate
    }
  });
  newSession = sessionResult[0];
} catch(e) {
  console.error(e);
}
```

Also, no need to use .then and .catch if you're using await. Use try/catch instead to catch the error.

Comment: You're welcome :) Not sure who downvoted it, but could you upvote it please

Comment: I was involving my self in callback hells. LOL! You quickly solved!

Comment: This is error when I try to upvode `Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.`